# How do you setup branches for a Bonobo Git Server repository?

Tags: git, git-flow, bonobo

I'm just starting to try to setup a Bonobo Git Server.  I don't see any way to setup branches in it?  I've seen discussions on permissions for branch folders so I know it can be done.  Is there a way to create branches from the web interface?

I will be using SourceTree to interface with it which I use GitFlow to work features and branches.  So wasn't sure if there was some other initial settings I need to do in Bonobo to setup the Master/Develop (and other) branches and features in it.

Also, we had been using a gitlab local server which recently crashed.  So the only working copies of our repositories are what's on the client computers.  I need to get the repositories back into the Bonobo Git server.  If anyone has any best step actions to do that I would appreciate knowing how to do that also.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have it solved already - but in my case I went into the Settings and I have two items checkmarked - "Allow user repository creation" and "Allow push to create repositories".

Now, when you're developing in your branch on local machine - when you push it up to the server it will create the branch if it's not already there.